# create generic method that returns instance of class passed in

Tags: java

I have the following method in a class. The AbstractModel is a generic being passed in by a class that extends this class. The method currently creates an instance of of the class passed in.

```
public AbstractModel newInstance(Class<? extends AbstractModel> clazz){

    return injector.getInstance(clazz);
}
```

Currently i have to do this:

```
Person person = (Person) em.newInstance(Person.class);
```

I'm wondering if i can use generics to remove the casting that i have to do to make the AbstractModel object a Person. Ideally just this:

```
Person person = em.newInstance(Person.class);
```

I don't know if this is possible since i'm not passing in a Person object to the method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the method signature to following -

```
public <T extends AstractModel> T newInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
```

Comment: is the portion in the carrots what must go into the method as a paramater and then the other T, the class that gets returned?

Comment: the ' < ' and ' > ' symbols

Comment: `<T extends AstractModel>` declares a type parameter `T` which is valid within the generic method `newInstance`. It's that `T` that we are using in the method parameter declaration (`Class<T> clazz`) and the return type (`T`).